# How to optimize google Chrome browser in Genymotion android emulator

Tags: android, selenium, emulation, appium, genymotion

My question today is about **optimizing google Chrome browser in Genymotion android emulator**. I've run my Selenium / Appium scripts just perfectly on my several real Samsung & HTC devices, even parallel. Since sometime I decided to try the same run on android emulators. To tell honestly, I've never tried original Android Studio virtual devices because they are extremely slow. When I run scripts on genymotion emulator custom installed google Chrome browser (means with the help of ARM translation and google apps zip files), the browser always behaves weirdly. Sometimes it randomly closes or just stuck. But the biggest problem is that browser is very slow. Text is being inserted into textfields slowly, pages are being reloaded slowly, images appears slowly as well. I've followed several advises from google search like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZKiqJyLBkU and others, but they just about optimizing emulator itself, not the Chrome browser. So far I have tried different versions of Emulators: Android **6.0** /  **5.0** /  **4.4** /   **4.3** /  all of them have slow chrome browser once custom installed. My Genymotion menu doesn't offer to create emulator with preinstalled Google Play (I assume that's because I use free version). The result of slow Chrome browser is my script always throws me a different errors on different runs so it makes no sense for me to resolve them as those scripts run excellent on real devices. If anybody overcame this problem with slowness of google Chrome browser for Genymotion emulator, please post your solutions here. Thanks.

Comment: did u try installing nexus emulators. they have chrome inbuilt

Comment: @karthick I'll try

Comment: @GordonFreaman any updates?

Comment: @nullpointer Well, the main update is that I decided just not to close virtualBox so this way I have some sort of static IPs for my emulators. Have to dive deeper in order to figure how to overcome this problem if virtual box is accidentally close or something else.